# Where to deploy NodeJS Express + MongoDB app in 2020

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment

I have an app that uses NodeJS+Express and MongoDB, which acts as an api for a Nuxt app. Where would you deploy it? I am using Heroku and MongoDB Atlas until now, but with load balancers the prices are getting higher.

I though on:

- VPS on Hostinger (seems like a bad idea)
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk (I tried this and the configuration and documentations are hell)
- Node Chef (Not sure if going this route, since it has some bad reviews) https://www.nodechef.com/
- Google Cloud Platform

Thanks in advance for some thoughs on this.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to replace the NodeJS+Express for your API to Nuxt.js [serverMiddleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware) instead. With this approach, you do not need to have additional compute instance to run NodeJS+Express, your API now runs together with your Nuxt app and the best thing is, minimum changes to your existing codes.

Based on my previous implementation, with this approach you can easily deploy your code to [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) or [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)

Comment: I have consider this, yes! Since the two apps are already developed and separated, then the refactor to fit the express app in the Nuxt app would be considerable. Also, could you tell me which advantages do you see on implementing a more monolithic architecture, likethe one you are proposing?

Comment: My suggested approach advantages are mainly to address the cost and security issues. Using Vue.js and Nuxt.js, when the app called APIs, you can easily inspect the API endpoints from the browser. So, your API endpoints are exposed.

But if you are calling APIs extensively, most of the times, I use serverMiddleware as an API proxy to call my internal and external API endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

The best platform which is also cost effective is Digital Ocean. You can use their App platform which is incredibly easy to setup and you should be up and running in 30 mins.

Comment: Do you think I would get a better deal than with Heroku or AWS?

Comment: You'll get a better deal than Heroku but AWS is pretty tight as you can use AWS for free up to 12 months depending on the resources you consume.